# Write to an alias directory on Apache

Tags: apache, virtualhost

How do I enable writing via PHP to an alias directory.

I have the following on my `VirtualHost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias m.domain.com

...etc

AliasMatch ^(.*)/user/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/images/(.*) "C:/Apache/webroot/user/$2/images/$3" 
<Directory "C:/Apache/webroot/user">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So if I tried to view a file or an image from `m.domain.com` I can see it being fetched from the `alias` directory; however, when I try to write it fails.

for example if i tried something like `<?php file_put_contents("user/sam/images/sample.png", $img); ?>` it would fail.

Any suggestions or ideas is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[file_put_contents](http://phpmanuals.net/en/function.file-put-contents.html) takes a file name, not webserver path.  When you put in a relative path from the context of the webserver, it interprets it relative to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

To save into an aliased directory, you would need to specify the abolute path of that directory.   There is a [question about how to get the absolute directory of users `public_html` folders on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079479/how-to-get-the-absolute-path-to-the-public-html-folder)

Comment: A relative path passed to `file_put_contents` is relative to the CWD, which may or may not be the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.